# Which python does % !TEX TS-program = pythontex use?

Tags: python, textmate, pythontex

On my macbook, I'm trying to run `pythontex` from Textmate using `% !TEX TS-program = pythontex` Here's a minimal document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pythontex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\pyb{print('Python says hi!')}
\end{document}
```

I want to run pythontex using anaconda python, which is my default python for terminal and Textmate python files.

Everything works fine if I run `pdflatex`, `pythontex`, `pdflatex` from terminal.

However, When I try to typeset the above document within Textmate, the `% !TEX TS-program = pythontex` line seems to be using Apple's python, `2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06)` which leads to an error about `pygments` not being installed.

Question: **How does `% !TEX TS-program = pythontex` determine what python to use?**? Why is it picking something besides my terminal and text mate default?

Comment: If I change PATH according to http://blog.macromates.com/2014/defining-a-path/ I get errors due to the fact that `pythontex` is passed `-interaction=nonstopmode` as if it were `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TextMate

I found this page http://blog.macromates.com/2014/defining-a-path/ and I went in the preferences of TextMate, changing (or adding) the setting for `PATH` as in the following picture

[image]

After enabling shell escape and running the test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{echo $PATH>\jobname.path}
\end{document}
```

the `.path` file that's created shows

```
/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
```

However, hitting Command-R shows errors related to `pythontex` being passed the options

-interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error

This is, in my opinion, a bug in the LaTeX bundle of TextMate.

If I remove the `TS-program` line and enable “Use latexmk” in the LaTeX bundle preferences, the correct `pythontex` call seems to be made.

### TeXShop

If you're using the `pythontex.engine` script distributed with TeXShop, it sets

```
PATH=~/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

It also has a commented out line

```
 #PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

and it's clear that both give preference to `/usr/bin/python`, that is the Apple distributed one (on my system it is version 2.7.5, because I'm still with 10.9.5 on this machine), unless, of course, you have Python in `~/anaconda/bin`.

If you want to use the Python version coming with Homebrew or other independent software distribution, you need to modify the setting of `PATH`. If your Python is in `/usr/local/bin`, just comment the first setting of `PATH` and uncomment the second one, but moving `/usr/local/bin` earlier than `/usr/bin`.

The location of `pythontex.engine` should be in

```
~/Library/TeXShop/Engines
```

Comment: you say "both give preferences to `/usr/bin/python`" but the first one starts with `~/anaconda/bin`, which is a Python installation. The [anaconda installer](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) can indeed install binaries in user repertory.

Comment: @jfbu Unless there is a Python executable in `~/anaconda/bin`, yes.

Comment: that would be the default after an anaconda installation; mine is actually in `/opt` not in  `~/` and  its `bin` sub repertory has `python` (which is a link to  `python3.4`), `ipython`, `spyder` (an IDE), etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix the binary path of Anaconda to the value of the `PATH` variable inside TextMate. For that purpose open `TextMate`→`Preferences…`→`Variables` and add the variable `PATH`:

[image: TextMate Preferences]

Then remove the line `% !TEX TS-program = pythontex` from your document. After that add the option `-shell-escape` and check `Use Latexmk` inside the bundle preferences (`Bundles`→`LaTeX`→`Preferences`):

[image: LaTeX Bundle — Preferences]

After that both “Typeset & View (PDF)” and “Watch Document” should work as expected.